# How to enforce parameter ordering in Jenkins DSL?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

We have a parameterized job that has three params: server, username, and password. We would like them to be presented in that order, but it looks like Jenkins DSL is alphabetizing them, as they are presented in the job as password, server, username. Is there any way to specify an ordering for the parameters other than lexigraphical, or should we just rename our parameters so they sort alphabetically? It's odd to enter a password, then a server, followed by the username to use. I'm also surprised that Jenkins DSL isn't using the declared order for ordering the params.

Here is the groovy definition, redacted as appropriate:

```
< snip >
job("myFolder/seed-jobname") {
  description('This job does stuff on a specified server')
  parameters {
    stringParam('SERVERNAME',
      '',
      'Enter the server to do stuff on'
    )
    stringParam('USERNAME', '', 'Enter your user ID')
    configure {
      it / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' / parameterDefinitions << 'hudson.model.PasswordParameterDefinition' { 
        name 'PASSWORD'
        description 'Enter your password'
        defaultValue ''
      }
    }
  }
< snip >
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins and Job DSL will keep the parameters in the specified order.

The problem with your snippet is that you put the configure block inside the parameters closure. `configure` is only available on `job` level. Calling it inside another closure will cause the configure block to execute before the containing closure. In your case the `PASSWORD` parameter is generated before the other parameters.

Try this:

```
job('example') {
  parameters {
    stringParam('SERVERNAME')
    stringParam('USERNAME')    
  }
  configure {
    it / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' / parameterDefinitions << 'hudson.model.PasswordParameterDefinition' { 
      name('PASSWORD')
    }
  }
}
```